# Javascript carousel not loading properly under some conditions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

So I've been working on a website, and the main focus of the site is a javascript-driven 3D carousel, and I got the code for the carousel from here: https://github.com/kaizouman/3dcarousel

I integrated the code into my site, and only modified the number of carousel items and the size of each item. I left the rest of the code untouched (demo.js and 3dcarousel.js). It works perfectly, but only most of the time. I've noticed that it'll work perfectly in Chrome about 90% of the time, in Safari about 80% of the time, and in Microsoft Edge & IE, it pretty much never works. When it doesn't work, it just loads each image individually. When it happens in Chrome, if I keep refreshing the page, it'll eventually work properly. Also interestingly, when I navigate to another page in Chrome and then hit the back button, the carousel will always fail to load.

Here's what it looks like in Microsoft Edge and also when it fails to load in Chrome: [image: fail]

And here's what it looks like when it loads properly: [image: success]

I can't for the life of me begin to figure out why this is happening, does anyone have any idea? The website is located at http://lipocircuit.com/new.html.

Answer (score 0):

WOW this was a simple fix, I just commented out the line that includes the prefixfree.min.js script, I guess that's outdated and not needed anymore. I feel dumb but I'll leave this up in case anyone else has this issue.